# Critique: How can I make my 'add post' website element stand out better?

Tags: website-design, critique

I'm working on building my own blogging website from the ground up, or at least that's what I assume that's what it will turn into at this point.

So far what I have built is fairly basic but one thing concerns me. I have an "Add Post" button that is inline with/on top of other posts but seems to blend into the flow of the site to well that it could easily be over looked.

Here is a **[link to the live website](http://simplyazuma.com/)** where you can play around with it.

[image]

**My question is, in what ways can I make the "Add Post" element stand out without affecting the overall look/feel of the website?**

Comment: I tried using bold font but it looks silly. I have thought of adding a "+" in the same fashion as the "X" is added on the posts but it would make it blend in even more I feel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have a neat thing going on here. Essentially you have a challenge with *meaning*. Because your Add New button is identical in presentation to the other rectangles on the page, it *means* the same thing as the other rectangles when a person sees it.

There are many ways to tackle an issue like this. User's graphic above is a very good example because it:

- stays within the colour palette
- indicates clearly an action with the big disc plus icon
- clarifies the action with the addition of the word New

Think about the fact that you will have other controls, (like the cool Delete Post slide-out), and choose a systematic way of expressing controls. Sort of a style guide that relates to the verbs of your app. An example off the top of my head:

- controls are always labelled in all caps
- control panels are grey
- control buttons are coloured: red for bad/stop, yellow for caution,
  green for go, and blue for informational
- control buttons always have a meaningful icon in two colours
- control buttons never have drop shadows

The result will be a family of controls that have consistency, fit within your interface and look cool.

[image: A quick hack]

Comment: This is a GREAT answer and explanation! I will play around with your suggestions and get back to you. :)

Comment: Oh yeah I forgot to mention in screen grab above: I changed the letter 'x' to a multiply sign '×' which is more square and iconic. Unicode: U+00D7 MULTIPLICATION SIGN
(X)HTML entities: &times;, &#215;
If you use UTF-8 as character encoding of your webpage, you can enter the character directly: ×

Comment: I definitely like that suggestion and made that change.

Comment: @MathewMacLean, I kinda like it [with a + to the left](http://i.stack.imgur.com/aRT1d.png) too

Comment: @Jon Thoughts on this now? http://simplyazuma.com/ not sure the green stands out enough, but I don't want to make it too crazy. And maybe it's just me, but the green looks out of place. Hmm...

Comment: I think that the green is too weak in this instance. I understand your hesitation to get too crazy, but you need to send clear signals to your user. It doesn't have to be green, but it does need to be distinctively not an entry. The back and white one with the big plus icon below works better than the hesitant green. Maybe mock up a page that has a collection of controls and then experiment with their colours in a family?

Comment: @Jon Good point, thanks for your input. I'll have to find a happy medium that doesn't take way from the layout too much.

Answer (score 1):

Just to give you a few ideas before I pop out:

[image: idea for site][image: idea for site]

I can't explain right now but I will revisit this later today/tomorrow when I can. At least the visuals are there and I hope it helps. :)

Comment: I definitely prefer the squared edges over the rounded as it fits with the design. Interesting idea so far.

Answer (score 0):

First I'd like to say you've done a really neat job of this, it's looking good. The interface is smooth and responsive.

My personal observations about this are;

- It might be better to have the 'Add Post' call to action as a completely different colour to the rest of the elements on there. It blends in a little too much for me at the moment.
- I feel that 'Add Post' should be somewhere else. It looks like a kind of status message to me, like if I'd just saved the post and it was confirmation of the fact. I can see why you put it at the top though, as with a larger number of posts it wouldn't be visible.

Nice job so far though.

Comment: Firstly, thank you for your comments. Secondly, I'm not sure if you visited the live site or not, but if you had it may make more sense why "add post" is where it is when you click it. :)

Comment: Yeah I had a play around. :) Don't get me wrong, where it is makes perfect sense. Just out of interest, what will happen when there are so many posts that I have to scroll. Will 'add post' stick to the top?

Comment: add them and find out! :D

Comment: Also, if you type in paragraphs or long content it will add a read more link.